# Metabase H2 to Postgresql permission error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, metabase

I migrate the Metabase H2 database to PostgreSQL. During step 4 on [tutorial available on their website](https://www.metabase.com/docs/v0.44/installation-and-operation/migrating-from-h2#4-run-the-migration-command), I stumbled upon the following error trace while `java -jar` command run. I host my Postgresql DB instance on AWS under the free tier plan. According to logs, the database has read-only permission. How can resolve this issue?

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: ERROR Set up h2 source database and run migrations...: The database is read only; SQL statement:
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET FILENAME = ? [90097-197] {}
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: The database is read only; SQL statement:
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET FILENAME = ? [90097-197]
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I could resolve the issue by using `sudo`. But `sudo` will fork and create a child process. All the environment variables you have set using `export` in the parent process will not be preserved in the child process. To resolve this, you have to add `-E` flag to the commands. In short, the command should be as follows:

```bash
export MB_DB_TYPE=postgres

export MB_DB_CONNECTION_URI="jdbc:postgresql://<host>:5432/metabase?user=<username>&password=<password>"

sudo -E java -jar metabase.jar load-from-h2 /path/to/metabase.db
```